# Playing Audio on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio, openal

I want to play prerecorded audio for users in an iPhone application.  Is the best way to play this audio to use openAL?  Is there any other way that might be beneficial for what I want to accomplish?

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most needs, I've found [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) to be an excellent choice for audio playback.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL covers most audio cases nicely and it is tied to the Core Audio so playback speed is never lagged. Based on what details you gave, OpenAL will take of your needs